# reducing roundtrip api requests on initial page load

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

Whenever I make a single-page HTML5 app, I generally have the following procedure:

- The user requests a page from the server, and the server responds
  with the appropriate html.
- Once the page returns, Javascript on the client-side requests documents from the server (the current user, requested docs, etc.)
- The client waits for yet another response before rendering, often resulting in a 'flicker' or necessitating a loading icon.

Are there any strategies for *preloading* the initial document requests and somehow attaching them -- a javascript object or array -- to the initial page response?

Comment: Not for the first load, because, by definition, the browser is loading the HTML for the first time, and knows as little as you. Do you use the history API or page fragments for storing your page state? If it's the history API, you could *also* include the required JS to setup the initial page in the HTML response.

Comment: a document (<html>) manifest attrib and manifest file can provide such.